# How can I manually lock an iPhone X screen

Tags: iphone

I have my iPhone X configured to auto-lock in 30 minutes. But sometimes I want to manually lock sooner, is this possible? By lock, I mean require the passcode.  I know that I could set the phone to require a passcode "Immediate" but, I would like to keep it set at 15 minutes for general use.  I only want to force it to require a passcode when I'm out for a run which is just 3 times a week.

I run with the iPhone, and sometimes find it's unlocked and in some unwanted state, due to unintended touches.

I don't have Face ID enabled I just require a Passcode. I know I can press the Side button to make the screen go dark. But for the next 15 minutes, all I need to *unlock* is swipe up. I want to lock it so that a Passcode is again required. That way when I'm running, nothing will happen other than me accidentally pressing the wrong numbers for the passcode.

Answer (score 4):

You can press the side button once to lock your iPhone X screen. This puts your iPhone to sleep mode and locks the screen (you'll be required to verify with facial attention or input passcode to unlock).

For more details, refer to the Apple Support article:

- [Use gestures to navigate your iPhone X and later](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208204)

> #### Wake and sleep
>
> [Raise to wake](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208081) or tap to wake your iPhone X.
>
> To put your iPhone X to sleep, press the side button.
>
> [image]

As pointed by [@ernie](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357480/how-can-i-manually-lock-an-iphone-x-screen/357482?noredirect=1#comment472333_357482), it's worth noting that an iPhone X with Face ID enabled unlocks as soon as you look at the screen when it is in awake state. To test that the screen was locked using this approach, you'll need to wake the device while *not* directly looking at the screen.

---

#### If you are not using Face ID

If you have turned off Face ID for your iPhone X, you'll need to enter your device Passcode to unlock. However, there's an additional setting which could prevent your device from going into *lock* mode after turning off the display by pressing the Side button. It is possible to set a time duration until which the iPhone is **not** locked (when you have turned off Face ID). To lock your iPhone immediately after putting the display to sleep after pressing the Side button, go to Settings app → Face ID & Passcode → Require Passcode and tap on **Immediately**.

[image]

Comment: I need to re-word the question to be clearer.  I'm looking in Lock as in require the passcode to open.  I'm set to 15 minutes until lock but I want to lock it right away in certain situations.  In your picture above, I want the lock icon to be closed, not open as shown.  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDyer Thanks for pointing out. It's reference image picked directly from the Apple support article. The device will indeed get locked and will require passcode upon pressing the side button. The image here is not used for depicting the locked state, but rather to indicate the location of the Side button.

Comment: @JohnDyer Sounds like you might have FaceID enabled, so it's locking, but you're not realizing it's locked since it unlocks as you try to verify the state?  You can test this by angling the camera off to the side or covering it while you press the side button (once to lock it, and once to turn the screen back on).

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble getting the question worded correctly.  I do not have face ID enabled.  I actually want to fully lock it so that again I need to enter the passcode.  See my edit to main question.

Comment: @JohnDyer Please go to Setting app → Face ID & Passcode → Require Passcode and set it to Immediately. As I understand it is set to something like 15 minutes or 1 hour. This may be preventing your iPhone from locking even after putting it on sleep mode by pressing the side button.

Comment: Yup, I know about the "Immediate" mode too.  I was hoping to keep it set at 15 minutes for general use.  But force a lock and passcode entry only now and then  (only when I go for a run).  I'll edit the question to clarify this point as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDyer It appears Siri doesn't honour the request to lock the screen (immediately) when asked to do so. Your only resort at the moment appears to be to manually change the time duration for "Require Passcode".

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is old but the answer may have come with the new OS. I’ll try with an old one to check.  I have my Lock Screen set to 15 minutes, but if you press and hold Volume Up and the right side button like you are trying to power down, then hit Cancel, it will immediately lock. So you can force a lock quicker than your settings by doing this. Most comments I think misunderstood the question.

So for the 99% of the time you want the Lock Screen delayed you have it set to whatever you want in settings. But if you want immediate lock without restarting then hold volume and right side and then cancel. Immediate lock.